# Can I exclude an exported package from a Java module?

Tags: java, java-9, jta, java-module

> Modules jta and java.sql export package javax.transaction.xa to module dom4j

As you can see, both modules `jta` and `java.sql` export the same package, `javax.transaction.xa`.  However, the package in `jta` has classes that I require that are not present in `java.sql`.  I would simply not require the `java.sql` module, but I need `java.sql.SQLException`.

Is it possible to prevent `java.sql` from exporting `javax.transaction.xa`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JTA GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jta-api) reads the following in confirmation to what @Alan already pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004100/can-i-exclude-an-exported-package-from-a-java-module#comment89007887_51004100) -

> This standalone release of Java(TM) Java Transaction API (JTA), uses a
>   Java Platform Module System "automatic" module name of
>   `java.transaction`, to match the module name used in JDK 9. A future
>   version will include full module metadata. Moreover
>   `javax.transaction.xa` package is now owned by Java SE.

You can use the version with Maven(e.g) using :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the [release notes for `JTA1.3MR`.](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr907/JTA1.3MR-November2017.pdf)

---

Additionally the ***[JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)*** elaborates on the same -

> ... The `javax.transaction.xa` package supports XA transactions in JDBC.
>   This ["XA package"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/transaction/xa/package-summary.html) is co-located with JDBC in the `java.sql` module in
>   Java SE 9. Because the `java.sql` module is not upgradeable, it is not
>   possible for a standalone version of JTA to override the Java SE
>   version of the XA package

and to further note for extensibility in your solution

> ...For ease of maintenance, the XA package in Java SE may be moved to a
>   different non-upgradeable module in the future, but as an
>   architectural matter it will remain in Java SE alongside JDBC for the
>   long term...

and as planned

> In early 2018, JTA 1.3 will be defined to consist of just the CORBA
>   interop package; the JAR file will be updated accordingly.

Comment: I was already aware of this *fix*, but I only managed to get it working by removing `module-info.java` and adding the modules via the command line instead (Spring doesn't want to cooperate with the module path :P).  Thanks though!

Comment: With JDK 9 and JDK 10, if you are deploying JTA 1.3 as a module then you need to deploy it on the upgrade module path so that it overrides the java.transaction module in the run-time image. That complication does not exist in JDK 11 as the java.transaction is proposed to be dropped from Java SE 11.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `javac -d -cp /PATHTOYOURFILE` `-d` and `-cp` flags to compile only required directories and classpath. Classpath can also be comma seperated.